# Bootstrap 3 hidden-xs class hiding column no matter the size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

the hidden-xs and visible-xs classes are not working for me. They are either hiding elements in all sizes or displaying in all sizes. Has anyone else run into this issue?

There is nothing special about my code at all. Here is an example of where this doesn't work:

```
<ul class="dot-nav visible-xs">
  <li><div class="dot-nav-dot"></div></li>
  <li><div class="dot-nav-dot"></div></li>
  <li><div class="dot-nav-dot"></div></li>
  <li><div class="dot-nav-dot"></div></li>
  <li><div class="dot-nav-dot"></div></li>
</ul>
```

The only styling is making it

```
display:none;
```

Comment: Lets see some code :-)? Bootstrap 3 version? Have you read the manual about these classes thoroughly? Are you using these in combination with other hidden- visible- classes? Who knows?

Comment: Yes, I have googled my fingers off looking for answers and apparently no one else has had this issue. I am using the most recent version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered my own question.

We are using bootstrap-sass so we can override breakpoints in responsiveness. For some reason xs was set to a max-width of 4999px. We overrode it to be smaller.

We are working in Rails using bootstrap sass, which makes it easy to disable responsiveness. We simply added this to our application.css to set our own breakpoints:

```
$screen-lg-min: 5000px;
$screen-sm-min: 5000px;
$screen-md-min: 600px;
$screen-xs-max: 599px;
```